# lm() producing many NAs for coefficients

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to run a regression using about 80 independent variables. The problem is that the last 20+ coefficients return NA. If I condense the range of data to within 60, I get coefficients for everything just fine. Why am I getting these NAs and how do I resolve it? I need to reproduce this code using all of these variables.

```
composite <- read.csv("file.csv", header = T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
composite <- subset(composite, select = -ncol(composite))
composite <- subset(composite, select = -Date)
model1 <- lm(indepvariable ~., data = composite, na.action = na.exclude)
```

composite is a data frame with 82 variables.

UPDATE:

What I have done is found a way to create an object that contains only the significantly correlated variables, to narrow the number of independent variables down.

I have a variable now: sigvars, which is the names of an object that sorted a correlation matrix and picked out only the variables with correlation coefficients >0.5 and <-0.5. Here is the code:

```
sortedcor <- sort(cor(composite)[,1])
regvar = NULL

k = 1
for(i in 1:length(sortedcor)){
  if(sortedcor[i] > .5 | sortedcor[i] < -.5){
    regvar[k] = i
  k = k+1
 }
}
regvar

sigvars <- names(sortedcor[regvar])
```

However, it is not working in my lm() function:

```
model1 <- lm(data.matrix(composite[1]) ~ sigvars, data = composite)
```

Error: Error in model.frame.default(formula = data.matrix(composite[1]) ~ sigvars,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'sigvars')

Comment: It results from the fact that in multiple regression, it is not possible to estimate more coefficients than the number of individuals.

Comment: Right, but I have 82 independents and I am only getting 60 or so coefficients. I need the other 22 coefficients that correspond to the independents.

Comment: By default, the last p-n variables are just discarded from the model in `R`.

Comment: Having seen your update, I heartily recommend that this be moved over to CrossValidated, with a more general perspective (i.e. "how do I deal with this problem?" rather than "how do I make my code work?").  Your problem is one of *dimension reduction* or *regularization*, which are very well-studied problems in statistics -- don't reinvent the wheel!

Answer (score 3):

You're likely running into a [degrees of freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_%28statistics%29) problem due to your high number of independent variables.

However, you can easily check for other problems with your regression by running the `gvlma` package. It's a highly lauded set of tests collectively called Global Validation of Linear Model Assumptions and was published in the Journal of the American Statistical Association.

Asides from degrees of freedom, you should be inspecting the underlying data for data errors, looking at [multicolinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicolinearity) in particular and doing other routine diagnostics such as testing the residuals (you can find them via `residuals`, `summary`, or in the model object), running a misspecification test (i.e. `resettest` or `ramsey`), etc.

Comment: That is a good point, which makes me wonder if R doesn't automatically detect multicollinearity and if it excluded the last variables because there was too much collinearity in the model.

Comment: @user2662565 Thanks. It can automatically drop variables due to what's called **perfect** multicollinearity, but it if I remember correctly it prints a related message if it does so. If you need to investigate further please paste any `error` messages or `warnings` so that we'll be able to tell what happened. You might also paste the results of `dim(dataframe)` where dataframe is the name of your modeling data object, so that we can know if it was a degrees of freedom problem.

Comment: this is *exactly* a problem of multicollinearity. If `n` (number of observations) <= `p` (number of predictor variables) then by definition you have an unidentifiable/perfectly multicollinear set of parameters.  (This is why I'm arguing this should go to CrossValidated -- if this doesn't make sense to you then you should be looking for statistical help, not programming help ...)

Comment: @BenBolker You're describing degrees of freedom but you're saying multicollinearity. They're different. CrossValidated would be a fine place for this question but I think StackOverflow is fair game too, because he's working in R and was trying to figure out what's wrong with his R code. It's a stat-focused language so the cross-over is inevitable.

Comment: I admittedly haven't thought about it too carefully, but I'm not sure that they're different issues in this *particular* context.  The reason I suggest CV is that *answering* this question beyond "that's what R does when there are unidentifiable parameters" requires a statistical, not a programming framework.  We'll see if two more people with sufficient rep to cast close/migrate-to-CV votes agree with me or not ...

Comment: @BenBolker CV is probably a better fit overall, tho I don't feel strongly about it. Multicollinearity is when explanatory variables are highly correlated with each other, thus they predict each other and their coefficients become meaningless. R kicks out perfectly collinear variables because otherwise there would be singularity in the matrix.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a "degrees of freedom problem" please? (I know what degrees of freedom means, so the Wikipedia link [while useful] doesn't answer my question -- I want to understand what the distinction is between saying that this particular problem is a "degrees of freedom problem" or a "multicollinearity problem"